# How to extract $\mathbf b$ from $M = a I + \mathbf b \cdot \mathbf S$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, hermitian-matrices

Any $2 \times 2$ hermitian matrix $M$ can be written
$$M = a I + \mathbf b \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma,\tag{1}$$
where $a \in \mathbb R$, $\mathbf b \in \mathbb R^3$, $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is the [Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector), and $\mathbf b \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma := \sum b_i \sigma_i$. This is because the identity matrix and the Pauli matrices make up a basis for the real vector space of $2 \times 2$ hermitian matrices. Moreover, given $M$, one can extract $a$ and $\mathbf b$ via
$$a = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr}(M), \quad b_i = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr}(\sigma_i M),\tag{2}$$
because the Pauli matrices are traceless and obey the identity
$$\sigma_j \sigma_k = \delta_{jk} I + i \epsilon_{jkl} \sigma_l,\tag{3}$$
where we use implicit summation over the repeated index $l$.

A generalization of the Pauli matrices that is of particular interest to physicists is the [higher spin matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins). Hence, say we replace the Pauli vector in (1) with a "vector" $\mathbf S$ of $d \times d$ spin matrices, yielding
$$M = a I + \mathbf b \cdot \mathbf S,\tag{4}$$
where now, of course, $M$ and $I$ are $d \times d$. (This is clearly not a general $d \times d$ hermitian matrix for $d > 2$, but more restricted.) **Is there then some simple way, similar to** (2)**, to extract $\mathbf b$ given $M$?**

I tried the cases $d = 3, 4$ in Mathematica and found that, indeed,
$$b_i \propto \; \mathrm{tr}(S_i M).\tag{5}$$
So I suspect this works in general, but my initial attempts at a simple proof have failed. The identity (3) does not hold for the higher spin matrices, because, while they do obey
$$[S_j, S_k] = i \epsilon_{jkl} S_l\tag{6}$$
much like the Pauli matrices (up to normalization), they do not obey the same anticommutation relations.

Answer (score 1):

These *traceless* × matrices $S_i$ are normalized such that
$$
\operatorname{Tr} (S_iS_j)= \delta_{ij} ~~f(d),
$$
where
$$
f(d)=  \frac{d(d^2-1)}{12} ~.
$$
(You already know the sequence  of *f(d)* :  1/2,2,5,10,35/2,28,... for *d* = 2,3,4,5,6,7, etc, from basic spin physics ($d=2s+1$), where the quadratic Casimir is but *s(s+1)*, so that $3\operatorname{Tr} S_3^2=ds(s+1)$.)

It is then evident that $$
b_i= \operatorname{Tr} (S_i M ) ~ / f(d). $$